# Gradle wrapper is not downloading the gradle bin zip

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradlew, gradle-wrapper

I've been scratching my head over this problem, can't seem to figure out at all what is going on.

So for context, I've been working with Maven all this while and the maven wrapper has never given this error, but this time the project requirements are to use gradle.
At first i didn't know what was going, and that it was the gradle wrapper that is causing the download error.
This is the error that i used to get before

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip'.
Gradle could not start your build.
Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
Could not create service of type GradleInternal using ServicesProvider.createGradleModel().
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().
class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Then i followed a few forums and posts, and figured it out that maybe it's not downloading properly, so i separately downloaded `gradle-8.0.2-bin.zip` and placed it in `<project-folder>/gradle/wrapper/<gradle-zip-here>` like this

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-8.0.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

now the download part is working properly but i'm getting a different error,

```
D:\Java\Spring\demo2\demo>%cd%\gradlew clean build --stacktrace
Downloading file:/D:/Java/Spring/demo2/demo/gradle/wrapper/gradle-8.0.2-bin.zip
...........10%............20%............30%............40%............50%............60%...........70%............80%............90%............100%

Welcome to Gradle 8.0.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
 - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
 - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
   > Could not create service of type GradleInternal using ServicesProvider.createGradleModel().
      > Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
         > Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.initialization.exception.InitializationException: Gradle could not start your build.
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:90)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:33)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleController using ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:901)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:826)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:611)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:674)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:318)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:302)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.lambda$new$0(AbstractBuildState.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.lazy.LockingLazy.get(LockingLazy.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.getBuildController(AbstractBuildState.java:104)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:66)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.BuildStateFactory.createRootBuild(BuildStateFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.createRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type GradleInternal using ServicesProvider.createGradleModel().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:901)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:826)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:611)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:674)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:318)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:302)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleControllerFactory.newInstance(DefaultBuildLifecycleControllerFactory.java:88)
        at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultBuildModelControllerServices$ServicesProvider.createBuildLifecycleController(DefaultBuildModelControllerServices.kt:116)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:899)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.configurationcache.DefaultBuildModelControllerServices$ServicesProvider.createGradleModel(DefaultBuildModelControllerServices.kt:107)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:899)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLookupException: Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:205)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:181)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$1.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:239)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CompileServices.registerGradleServices(CompileServices.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices.lambda$new$0(GradleScopeServices.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.register(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:216)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices.<init>(GradleScopeServices.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServiceRegistryFactory.createFor(BuildScopeServiceRegistryFactory.java:36)
        at org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.<init>(DefaultGradle.java:99)
        at org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AsmBackedClassGenerator$InvokeConstructorStrategy.newInstance(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:1948)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator$GeneratedClassImpl$GeneratedConstructorImpl.lambda$newInstance$0(AbstractClassGenerator.java:510)
        at org.gradle.internal.deprecation.DeprecationLogger$4.create(DeprecationLogger.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.deprecation.DeprecationLogger.whileDisabledThrowing(DeprecationLogger.java:273)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator$GeneratedClassImpl$GeneratedConstructorImpl.newInstance(AbstractClassGenerator.java:509)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.doCreate(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:64)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultJdkToolsInitializer.initializeJdkTools(DefaultJdkToolsInitializer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CompileServices$GradleScopeCompileServices.configure(CompileServices.java:55)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:203)
        ... 113 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

I'm using java 17 and gradle version 8

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
                                                                  1
```